# What is the proper way to create a brush from a color?

Tags: c#, .net, gdi+

What is the proper way to create a brush from a color?  I've tried `Brush b = new Brush(color);` but [`Brush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.brush(v=vs.110).aspx) but that isn't allowed.  I can get existing colors using [`Brushes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.brushes(v=vs.110).aspx), but that doesn't have a way to create a specific brush.  I'm using my to fill a rectangle with solid color.

The current code I have involves creating a [`Pen`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.pen(v=vs.110).aspx) and then taking its `Brush`, but that doesn't seem like the right way:

```
Brush b = new Pen(color).Brush;
```

What is the correct way I should go about doing this?

Comment: do you need a `SolidBrush`?

Comment: do you need GDI+ or WPF?

Comment: @DanielA.White I don't exactly know the difference between the two, but I'm pretty sure I need GDI+.  I didn't even know there were two; I'm somewhat knew to this stuff.  It's the `System.Drawing` type.

Comment: `System.Drawing` is GDI+. `System.Windows.Media` is WPF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two current answers cover the two likely possibilities; if you're using GDI+ you want `new SolidBrush(color)` and if you're using WPF you want `new SolidColorBrush(color)`.

The reason is that with either, `Brush` is an abstract class that covers a range of possible brushes that could tile a bitmap or apply a gradient or otherwise paint with something other than just a single colour.

Answer (score 2):

Try creating a new `SolidBrush` for GDI+:

```
 SolidBrush mySolidBrush = new SolidBrush(color);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create [SolidColorBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.solidcolorbrush.aspx):

```
Brush b = new SolidColorBrush(color);
```

Comment: @DanielA.White OP linked to MSDN articles about WPF classes, so I assume this is what they need.

Comment: the link to Pen is for GDI+.